# Defining repeated tabular/array columns using a computed value to specify the number

Tags: tables, counters, arrays

### Background:

I just recently saw that one could define multiple columns in a `tabular` or `array` using the syntax:

```
*{num}{<align>}
```

So, for example `\begin{tabular}{r*{3}{l}r}` is the identical to `\begin{tabular}{rlllr}`, and similarly for `array`.

### Problem:

I used this to produce a solution to [Best way to create an system of equations environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35174/best-way-to-create-an-system-of-equations-enviroment/35235#35235)  where the number used was provided as a parameter. This works fine if the specified parameter is one less than the number of variables.

So, I attempted to modify this to accept the actual number of variables, and set that to a counter value, decrement it by one, and use the new value of the counter to specify how many of these were to be used.  I suspect that this is an expansion issue (which I haven't quite gotten the hang of).

Alternatively, if I could somehow perform a decrement operation and apply that value to the column specification would be fine as well.

#### Incorrect Result:

Currently, the code below produces:
[image]

#### Desired Result:

I would like to use something equivalent to the intent of the commented `\begin{array}` that uses a value of one less than the provided parameter. So when this works as desired, the output should be (note the shift in the right vertical bar):
[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.7in]{geometry}

\newcounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}
\newenvironment{MySystem}[2]{% <num+1> <r|l|c>
    \setcounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}{#1}
    \addtocounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}{-1}
    \begin{array}{c| *#1{#2} | c}% want to replace this with something equivalent to line below 
    %\begin{array}{c| *{\the\value{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}}{#2}}%
        \the\value{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}\\
}{%
    \end{array}%
}


\newcommand{\data}{123 & abc & de  & f \\1   & a   & def & fg}%

\begin{document}
\color{red}
$\begin{MySystem}{4}{r}
    \data
\end{MySystem}$
\hspace{0.5in}
$\begin{MySystem}{4}{l}
    \data
\end{MySystem}$

\color{blue}
$\begin{MySystem}{3}{r}
    \data
\end{MySystem}$
\hspace{0.5in}
$\begin{MySystem}{3}{l}
    \data
\end{MySystem}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: But egreg's answer to [what is the proper method of accesing a counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter) seems to indicate otherwise. Or, did I misunderstand his answer?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Ah, so much left to learn...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\newcounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}
\newenvironment{MySystem}[2]{% <num+1> <r|l|c>
    \setcounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}{#1}
    \addtocounter{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}{-1}
    \begin{array}{c| *{\theNumberOfRepeatedColumns}{#2} | c}
}{%
    \end{array}%
}
```

or even better, without the extra counter, and `\numexpr`:

```
\newenvironment{MySystem}[2]{% <num+1> <r|l|c>
    \begin{array}{c| *{\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2} | c}
}{%
    \end{array}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that, but I guess my real problem was that I was missing the `c` for the last column. So `\begin{array}{c| *{\the\value{NumberOfRepeatedColumns}}{#2} | c}` works as well.