# Aligning linear systems of equations

Tags: vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to create an system of equations enviroment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35174/best-way-to-create-an-system-of-equations-enviroment)

What do I need to do to get my systems of linear equations to align at each of the addition/subtraction/equals signs without manually adding silly things like \phantom{2} in front of variables with coefficient 1? Here's a general example where the + signs in the last equation are not vertically aligned with the + signs in the first two equations (not to mention the fiddling I did to get the vertical dots to be in a reasonable place):

```
\begin{align*}
   a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n & = b_1 \\
   a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \cdots + a_{2n}x_n & = b_2 \\
   \hspace{1in}\vdots \hspace{.8in} \\
   a_{m1}x_1 + a_{m2}x_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}x_n & = b_m \\
\end{align*}
```

A more specific example:

```
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 &= 8 \\
-x_1 -2 x_2 + 3x_3 &= 1 \\
3x_1 -7 x_2 + 4x_3 &= 10 \\
\end{align*}
```

Should I just give up on align and use array?

Comment: `alignat` is good here: see [these related questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=systems+of+equations)

Comment: Ah, you are correct, egreg. For some reason that question never came up in the multiple times I have searched system of equations. Thanks!

Comment: However, I would still like to know if there's a simpler way than those suggested in the answers to that question.

Comment: Stephan's answer in the linked question is pretty simple :)