# Unable to use systeme for a system of equations with \ldots and non-numeric coefficients

Tags: equations, systeme

I just found in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35176/4011, that using the `systeme` package ist probably the best way to typeset a system of linear equations in LaTeX.

Now I tried to generate a general system of linear equations like in this approach but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\sysdelim..
\systeme{%
a_11 x_1 + a_12 x_2 + \dots + a_1m x_m = b_1, 
a_21 x_1 + a_22 x_2 + \dots + a_2m x_m = b_2, 
%%Here I should add some vertical and diagonal dots
a_n1 x_1 + a_n2 x_2 + \dots + a_nm x_m  = b_n
}%

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to make this work without making the syntax too complex?

Comment: Creating a new package-specific tag is good practice; I added a fitting general tag to attract more attention from potential answerers.

Comment: the package documentation (`texdoc systeme`) shows no examples using dots either vertically or horizontally, and the string *dot* isn't present in the documentation.  i think the package may not cover this situation, but can't be sure because the documentation is in french, and i'm sure i'm missing some of the important points.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, you might be right. But then I wonder that it is such highly voted in the other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35174/best-way-to-create-an-system-of-equations-environment/35176#35176 as the best solution to such a basic task...

Comment: the package looks very nice for what it handles.  i haven't looked at the code, but think it might be worth writing to the author (name and e-mail address in the documentation) to ask for a possible extension.

Answer (score 4):

The `systeme` package cannot work with non-numeric coefficients.
But you can build your own macro to copy how `systeme` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\typesystem#1{%
    \begingroup\expandarg
    \baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip% 1.5 to enlarge vertical space between lines
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}+{&+&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem={&=&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem,{\noexpand\cr}[\tempsystem]%
    $\vcenter{\halign{&$\hfil\strut##$&${}##{}$\cr\tempsystem\crcr}}$%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
my system : \typesystem{
a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \ldots + a_{1m} x_m = b_1,
a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + \ldots + a_{2m} x_m = b_2,
\vdots\hfil&&           &&       &&\vdots\hfil= \vdots,
a_{n1} x_1 + a_{n2} x_2 + \ldots + a_{nm} x_m = b_m
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For future readers: Replace `\left\{` in the line before `\endgroup` by `\left.` to get rid of the curly brace (as setting `\sysdelim` in my question would do).

Comment: There is a problem with the alignment of the vdots after the = sign. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: as well as the vdots being too far to the right, the *b*s on the right-hand side aren't aligned.  it appears that the whole last column is aligned at the right.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, replace `\noexpand`\ by `hfil`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\sysdelim.
\systeme{
\noindent 
$ a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \ldots + a_{1m} x_m = b_1,\\
a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + \ldots + a_{2m} x_m = b_2,\\ 
\vdots\\
a_{n1} x_1 + a_{n2} x_2 + \ldots + a_{nm} x_m = b_m
$
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got this compiled in shareLaTeX and posted the answer..

Comment: the blank line between `\systeme{` and its closing brace will trigger the "paragraph ended" error.  tex requires that math expressions be complete with no paragraph breaks.  and according to the package documentation (`texdoc systeme`; it's in french), no double backslashes are used at the ends of lines, only commas.  unfortunately, i can 't help with the other problems.

Comment: @student , I have modified the code. It works now. I have used TeXLive 2013 and TeXMaker

Comment: Thanks. Now it works for me too. Is it also possible to get the vertical dots such as in unbonpetit's answer? By the way it should be `b_n` and not `b_m`.