# Issues with system of equations: systeme fix and align environment

Tags: equations, align, xstring, systeme

I'm writing some notes on linear algebra and to ease my work I've decided to use the `systeme` package. When I discovered that systeme has no built-in feature of writing systems of equations with dots and non-numeric coefficients, I've decided to use the fix suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160756).

I need to write the full process of row-reduction of a specific system of equations, and I've done it before using the cases environment inside an align* environment. But the cases environment won't align the coefficients as desired, although each system is just where I wanted it to be. The fix suggested in this post yields an error when used inside the align* environment. What can I do?

A test sample for the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\typesystem#1{%
    \begingroup\expandarg
    \baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip% 1.5 to enlarge vertical space between lines
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}+{&+&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem={&=&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem,{\noexpand\cr}[\tempsystem]%
    \vcenter{\halign{&$\hfil\strut##$&${}##{}$\cr\tempsystem\crcr}}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \left\{\typesystem{3x + 2y = 1, x - 3y = 2}\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It yields:

```
! Argument of \@xs@next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.20 \end{align*}
```

My situation in which each system is where it's desired but the coefficients inside them are not aligned (using align* and cases):

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i'm a bit puzzled as to what, exactly, you would like to be lined up.  is it that (for example) all the "case braces" on the right-hand side should be in line vertically, or that all instances of `x_1` on the left side should end at the same horizontal point (and similarly within the cases on the right-hand side), or a combination of all these things?  or something else?  i'm thinking that `alignat*` might be more appropriate here, at least with regard to the three cases on the right-hand side.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks! Ideally, I would like everything lined up - the arrows having all the same length, the case braces in line vertically and all instances of the variables (even when they are missing) to end at the same horizontal point. But if only the last one is achievable (or at least without much manual whitespace tweaking), that's fine for me. I'll have to write lots of systems, some of them with dots and non-numeric coefficients, so efficiency comes first here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stay with `systeme` as the code for `\typesystem` is *very* faulty.

Anyway, an additional pair of braces will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xstring}

\newcommand\typesystem[1]{%
    \begingroup\expandarg
    \linespread{1.5}\selectfont
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}+{&+&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem-{&-&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem={&=&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem{\noexpand\missing}{{}&&}[\tempsystem]%
    \StrSubstitute\tempsystem,{\noexpand\cr}[\tempsystem]%
    \left\{\vcenter{\halign{&$\hfil\strut##$&${}##{}$\cr\tempsystem\crcr}}\right.%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand\minus{{-}}
\newcommand{\missing}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
{\typesystem{
  2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 1,
  4x_1 - 3x_2 + x_3 = 0,
  \minus x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = \minus2
}}
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_2\rightarrow L_2 - 2L_1}{}
&{\typesystem{
  2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 1,
{} - x_2 + 3x_3 = \minus2,
  \minus x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = \minus2
}}
\\
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_1\leftrightarrow L_3}{}
&{\typesystem{
  \minus x_1 +x_2 +2x_3 = \minus2,
{} - x_2 +3x_3 = \minus2,
  2x_1 -x_2 -x_3 = 1
}}
\\
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_3\rightarrow L_3 + 2L_1}{}
&{\typesystem{
  \minus x_1 +x_2 +2x_3 = \minus2,
{}  - x_2 +3x_3 = \minus2,
\missing  x_2 +3x_3 = \minus3
}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `systeme`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\systeme{
  2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 1,
  4x_1 - 3x_2 + x_3 = 0,
  -x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = -2
}
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_2\rightarrow L_2 - 2L_1}{}
&\systeme{
  2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 1,
  -x_2 + 3x_3 = -2,
  -x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = -2
}
\\
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_1\leftrightarrow L_3}{}
&\systeme{
  -x_1 +x_2 +2x_3 = -2,
  -x_2 +3x_3 = -2,
  2x_1 -x_2 -x_3 = 1
}
\\
&& {}\xrightarrow{L_3\rightarrow L_3 + 2L_1}{}
&\systeme{
  -x_1 +x_2 +2x_3 = -2,
  -x_2 +3x_3 = -2,
  x_2 +3x_3 = -3
}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is probably overkill, but wouldn't phantom minus signs be appropriate in the right-hand side for the non-negative equalities?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think that `\typesystem` is inadequate anyway, so I didn't bother too much. A better definition of `\minus` is `\newcommand{\minus}{{-}}`, which I edited in.

Comment: uh, i was actually referring to the example with `\systeme`, since you had explicitly deprecated `\typesystem`.  (i *did* read your explanations.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, I misread your comment. There's an answer of mine for getting right alignment in the right-hand side: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247078/4427

Comment: that's a nice one!  mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tabstackengine` alternative for presenting systems of equations.  However, because we are using a space as the term separator, the syntax is rigid and one cannot freely throw in stray blank spaces.  In general, things to remember are:

1. if one wants the operators (`+`, `-`, `=`) to line up, then they can not attached to either term (i.e., must form their own column);  If right alignment of the terms is all that is required, without operator alignment, then operators can be placed next to leading or trailing terms **as long as you are consistent in the syntax across all equations of the system**;
2. `{}` is used as a placeholder for an empty term;
3. In order to achieve this syntax, leading minus signs will be treated as a binary operation, unless presented as `{-}`;
4. stray spaces are a no-no, including leading and trailing spaces, as well as those surrounding the comma `,` equation separator.

Here is the MWE.

In response to barbara's comment, here is what the result looks like if I group the leading minus signs as `{-}` instead of `-`, to prevent them from being treated as binary operators.  Additionally, to show flexibility of the solution, the inter-line baselineskip can be set in the preamble, e.g., `\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\typesystem#1#2{\savestack{#1}{\setstackEOL{,}\setstackTAB{ }
  $\left\{\ensurestackMath{\tabbedCenterstack[r]{#2}}\right.$}}
\TABbinary
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{12pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\typesystem{\systemA}{2x_1  - x_2  - x_3  =    1,4x_1 - 3x_2 +  x_3 =    0,{-}x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = {-2}}
\typesystem{\systemB}{2x_1  - x_2  - x_3  =    1,{}   - x_2  + 3x_3 = {-}2,{-}x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = {-2}}
\typesystem{\systemC}{{-}x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = {-2},{}   - x_2  + 3x_3 = {-}2,2x_1   - x_2 - x_3  =  1}
\typesystem{\systemD}{{-}x_1 +x_2  +2x_3  = {-2},{}   -x_2   +3x_3  = {-}2,{} x_2 +3x_3        = {-3}}
\typesystem{\systemE}{{-}x_1 +x_2  +2x_3  = {-2},{}   -x_2   +3x_3  = {-}2,{} {}  +6x_3        = {-5}}

\systemA\quad
\alignShortunderstack{%
  \xrightarrow{L_2\rightarrow L_2 - 2L_1}&\systemB\\
  \xrightarrow{L_1\leftrightarrow L_3}&\systemC\\
  \xrightarrow{L_3\rightarrow L_3 + 2L_1}&\systemD\\
  \xrightarrow{L_3\rightarrow L_3 + L_2}&\systemE
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a try, and it also works fine with dots (vdots included). I couldn't make it work straight away with non-numerical coefficients, but I'll lookup it's documentation to see what may be done.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza Since I am the package author, I would be happy to look further, if I can understand the requirements better.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza Please see my revision.

Comment: small quibble ... the space between the braces and what follows looks too "generous" to me.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As I said in my answer (point 3), leading minus signs are treated as binary, unless grouped separately as `{-}`.  See addendum.

Comment: binary or unary, that's irrelevant; the binary nature isn't in respect to the "case" braces, only to what follows.  that said, the "tightened" version looks a lot better (and more "normal") to me.  thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You can say it is irrelevant, but compare `x${}-Z$\par x$-Z$` to see why the extra space is introduced by adding a blank group before the `-`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'll stay with the other solution for now as it doesn't involve changing my current package selection and editing older files much. I thanks for your suggestion, and I'll keep in mind this alternative! Using non-numerical coefficients on the linear system seems still a major feature missing in `systeme`, and if it is/becomes a feature of`tabstackengine` I will be surely very inclined to give it a try, as I'll  need it a lot soon (to write arbitrary systems, with equations such as `a_{11}x_1 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n = b_n`, for example).

Comment: please compare the content of these two components: on the right side, the first line of the first case group, and the third line of the second case group.  the purported content is identical, but the presentation is different.  taking into account your warnings, i tried to make the output consistent, but everything i tried only made things worse.  it seems that this approach is quite fragile.  how might one fix these two elements to make the presentation the same?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I realize if one wants to line up all the operators, they must be in their own columns, separated by spaces (unless the special case arises that all coefficients are equal width).