# Long series alignment

Tags: align

I have three long sums (series) on three lines and want all plus signs be aligned vertivally just like in LaTeX code.

```
\begin{align}
x          &= 1 \cdot x &+ 0   \cdot x^2 &+ 0   \cdot x^3 &+ 0   \cdot x^4 &+ 0   \cdot x^5 &+ \ldots \\
x A_F(x)   &= 0 \cdot x &+ F_1 \cdot x^2 &+ F_2 \cdot x^3 &+ F_3 \cdot x^4 &+ F_4 \cdot x^5 &+ \ldots \\
x^2 A_F(x) &= 0 \cdot x &+ 0   \cdot x^2 &+ F_1 \cdot x^3 &+ F_2 \cdot x^4 &+ F_3 \cdot x^5 &+ \ldots
\end{align}
```

But result looks very bad.[image]
Which environment should I use?

Comment: Is this helpful? [Best way to create an system of equations environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35174)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `alignat`, with some tricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{5}
%         R L              L R             R L  L R             R L  L R             R L  L R             R L
x          &= 1 \cdot x +{} & 0   \cdot x^2 &+{} & 0   \cdot x^3 &+{} & 0   \cdot x^4 &+{} & 0   \cdot x^5 &+ \dotsb \\
x A_F(x)   &= 0 \cdot x +{} & F_1 \cdot x^2 &+{} & F_2 \cdot x^3 &+{} & F_3 \cdot x^4 &+{} & F_4 \cdot x^5 &+ \dotsb \\
x^2 A_F(x) &= 0 \cdot x +{} & 0   \cdot x^2 &+{} & F_1 \cdot x^3 &+{} & F_2 \cdot x^4 &+{} & F_3 \cdot x^5 &+ \dotsb
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The tricks are meant so that every power of *x* appears in an odd numbered column, whereas the + signs are in even numbered columns. The `{}` ensure correct spacing.

The R and L tells you what's the alignment at either side of `&`

[image]

Comment: But I can't understood the magic. Why there are two && in one of the columns? And what exactly {} does?

There is very poor reference of alignat in the amsmath docs so I didn't fully det it. Maybe, there is somewhere better description?

Comment: @qx87 I removed the `&&`, that had remained from a previous attempt. Basically, `\begin{alignat}{<n>}` sets up `<n>` pair of “right-left” aligned columns, with no space between each pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `\halign`:

```
$$
\vbox{\baselineskip=1.2\baselineskip \halign{\hfil$\displaystyle#{}$&&\hfil$\displaystyle#{}$\cr
  x          =& 1\cdot x +& 0\cdot x^2   +& 0\cdot x^3   +& 0\cdot x^4 +& 0\cdot x^5     +& \cdots \cr
  x A_F(x)   =& 0\cdot x +& F_1\cdot x^2 +& F_2\cdot x^3 +& F_3\cdot x^4 +& F_4\cdot x^5 +& \cdots \cr
  x^2 A_F(x) =& 0\cdot x +& 0\cdot x^2   +& F_1\cdot x^3 +& F_2\cdot x^4 +& F_3\cdot x^5 +& \cdots \cr
}}$$
```

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, here's a LaTeX-based solution that uses just a basic `array` environment. That way, it's not necessary to enter the `=` and `+` symbols -- LaTeX can do this for you.

Note that I would used `\cdots` instead of `\ldots` for the typographic ellipses at the end of each equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ r@{{}={}} *{5}{r@{{}+{}}} c}
x          & 1 \cdot x & 0   \cdot x^2 & 0   \cdot x^3 & 0   \cdot x^4 & 0   \cdot x^5 & \cdots \\
x A_F(x)   & 0 \cdot x & F_1 \cdot x^2 & F_2 \cdot x^3 & F_3 \cdot x^4 & F_4 \cdot x^5 & \cdots \\
x^2 A_F(x) & 0 \cdot x & 0   \cdot x^2 & F_1 \cdot x^3 & F_2 \cdot x^4 & F_3 \cdot x^5 & \cdots
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The original has `align`, so the lines are numbered.

Comment: @egreg - Indeed, this solution doesn't provide individual equation numbers. Let's see if the OP weighs in and states how important it is to him/her to have separate equation numbers.