# Aligning Systems of Equations

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm trying to line up the variables of systems of equations. The following code:

```
$$\left\\{
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha + 2&\beta + &\gamma & = 0 \\\\
3&\alpha + 7&\beta + 5&\gamma & = 1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
```

produces the following image:

[image]

I want the Greek letters and the math symbols to be aligned, with appropriate spacing in between coefficients. I've tried using `\begin{aligned} \end{aligned}` and `\begin{array}{ll} \end{array}{ll}` as well, but they also don't provide the desired outcome.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me out? Thank you.

Comment: You can try the package `systeme`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme .

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35174/best-way-to-create-an-system-of-equations-environment

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, do not use `$$ ... $$`, which is plain TeX, use the LaTeX construct `[ ... \]`.

Second, 4 alignment points require  7 ampersands, not 4: each new column of alignment has to be introduced by an ampersand. So n alignment points require 2n–1 ampersands.

Last: use `alignat` (or `alignedat`) to have full control on the spacing between columns of alignment.

Here is a possible code:

```
\[ \left\{
\begin{alignedat}{4}
&\alpha &{} + 2&\beta + {} & &\gamma & & = 0 \\\\
3&\alpha &{} + 7&\beta + 5 & &\gamma & & = 1
\end{alignedat}
```

However, using the `systeme` package makes it simpler to type:

```
\[ \systeme[\alpha\beta\gamma]{\alpha + 2\beta +\gamma = 0, 3\alpha + 7\beta + 5\gamma = 1} \]
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea that $ was plain TeX, thanks! Unfortunately it seems that for the Github Markdown I'm trying to edit, `\[` doesn't seem to work... But `\begin{alignedat}{4} \end{alignedat}` works perfectly!

Comment: I've updated with a simpler way to type (the `\systeme` command from the homonymous package).

Comment: In your first method, the spacing around the `=` is not correct.

Comment: Oh! yes. I had a bad count of `&`. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Is there a documentation that I could reference to further understand the answer? Thanks.

Comment: `\amsldoc` (amsmath documentation) and `systeme`. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious.. When do we use the empty curly braces, and how do we know when to use two ampersands rather than one?

Comment: The empty curly braces are there because $+$ (or $-$) are `binary operators` with a special spacing w.r.t. the elements on the right and on the left. This can be destroyed by an ampersand, and to compensate, one has to add an empty argument, namely `{}`. For the number of `&`, maybe I was not clear enough: each column of alignment, but the first, has to be introduced by an &. Inside this column, the alignment point is specified with another &. Check on my code, you should see this rule is respected. Is this clear?

Comment: Yes, it's clear! Thanks for the extra clarification. :)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\Matrixstack[r]{
\alpha  +& 2\beta +&  \gamma =& 0 \\
3\alpha +& 7\beta +& 5\gamma =& 1
}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that requires only the basic `array` package. The following code also sets up a custom `array`-like environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
%% set up a little custom enrironment:
\newenvironment{myarray}[1]{%
   \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
   \left\{ \begin{array}{#1}}{%
   \end{array} \right.}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{myarray}{rCrCrCl}
 \alpha &+& 2\beta &+&  \gamma &=& 0 \\
3\alpha &+& 7\beta &+& 5\gamma &=& 1
\end{myarray}
\]
\end{document}
```