# How can I align the terms of this equation nicely?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I have the following `alignat` segment:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \text{max}_{\underline{\lambda}} \text{min}_{\underline{x}} \quad & \underline{c}^T \underline{x} + \underline{\lambda}^T(\underline{d} - D\underline{x}) \\
  \text{s.t.} \quad & A \underline{x} & \leq \underline{b} \\
                    & \underline{x}   & \geq \underline{0}
\end{alignat*}
```

which gives

[image: LaTeX Result]

however, the result I'm aiming for is more like

[image: Desired Result]

Note that:

- the 'max/min' is right-aligned with the 's.t.', the left-most character in the list of 's.t.' terms (the A) is aligned with the left-most term in the objective function (the c).
- the rest of the LHS in the 's.t.' section is right-aligned, and the inequalities are aligned.

I'm not sure if I'm being too fussy here, but anything is better than what I already have.

Comment: Why use `\text{max}` instead of `\max` and `\min`?

Comment: Because I didn't know about \max and \min :) But now that I know about them, I will start using them!

Comment: Here are four other ideas: [How to edit the linear programming in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75108) And here are five others: [Multicol layout for systems of (linear) equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6965).

Comment: @Ozzah Then you should probably also learn about \log, \exp, \sin, \cos, etc.  Also, if you want to define a new math operator, simply use [\DeclareMathOperator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator).

Comment: Other [log-like symbols](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (pdf) are \arccos, \arcsin, \arctan, \arg, \cos, \cosh, \cot, \coth, \csc, \deg, \det, \dim, \exp, \gcd, \hom, \inf, \ker, \lg, \lim, \liminf, \limsup, \ln, \log, \max, \min, \Pr, \sec, \sin, \sinh, \sup, \tan, \tanh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use `aligned` environment from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \max_{\underline{\lambda}} \min_{\underline{x}} \quad & \underline{c}^T \underline{x} + \underline{\lambda}^T(\underline{d} - D\underline{x}) \\
  \text{s.t.} \quad &  \begin{aligned}[t]
     A \underline{x} & \leq \underline{b} \\
     \underline{x}   & \geq \underline{0}
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: (The `amsmath` package which is loaded by `mathtools` provides `aligned`.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks for that. I was having trouble compiling when I added that package, and couldn't see it in my MiKTeX package repository.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks. For some reason I believed that `aligned` was part of `mathtools`. I have corrected the statement in the answer.